# Objective-C Hashable object for Diffable Data Source

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, diffabledatasource, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

I am trying to implement a collection view with a diffable data source in Objective-C. I know for Swift, the generic types for UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource are types that conform to both the Hashable and Identifiable protocols. But I do not know what these correspond to for Objective-C.

So my question is if I have a data source property like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<NSString *, MyItemType *> *dataSource;
```

Then what do I need to implement in `MyItemType` to make it work correctly? Is it sufficient to just implement the following methods or are these not correct and I need to implement something else for Objective-C?

- `- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object`
- `- (NSUInteger)hash`
- `- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(MyItemType *)other`

And what protocol(s) do I need to adopt for my model object?

#### MyItemType.h

Here is the definition of the model item. These are displayed in a collection view list layout.

```objectivec
@interface MyItemType : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (strong, nonatomic, nullable) NSString *subtitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic, nullable) NSArray<MyItemType *> *children;
@property (strong, nonatomic, nullable) UIImage *image;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource):

```
class UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<SectionIdentifierType, ItemIdentifierType> : NSObject where SectionIdentifierType : Hashable, ItemIdentifierType : Hashable
```

`ItemIdentifierType` must only be Hashable. `NSObject` already conforms to `Hashable`, but, by default it only compares instance identity (e.g. pointer):

- `==` calls `-isEqual:`, default `-isEqual:` compares `self` pointers,
- `hashValue` calls `-hash`, default `-hash` returns `self` pointer (cast to `NSUInteger`).

For `MyItemType`, being a subclass of `NSObject` it is sufficient to only override `-isEqual:` and `-hash`.

Some good links:

- https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-06-18-implementing-equality-and-hashing.html
- https://nshipster.com/equality/
- "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" book in Apple Books